# Processing POST request in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, request

Hi I got a simple form for a POST request and it works when I'm only having one input, but not two inputs together. Can someone show me some light on this?

index.html

```
<form name="input" action="{% url 'sending' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    Recipient: <input type="text" name="recipient"> 
    <br>
    Message: <input type="text" name="content"> 
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

views.py

```
def sending(request):
    recipient = request.POST.get('recipient','')
    content = request.POST.get('content','')   #not working when I am doing this...

    someMethod(recipient, content)

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results'))
```

Comment: just to note that when I'm saying not working, I dont get any error or such, it just keep loading on the browser...

Comment: What does someMethod do? Does it get called? Can you put some logging or print statements inside that method to see where it gets to?

Comment: the someMethod basically takes the recipient and content variables and do some manipulation with it. It works when I tested with hard coded data like content = "testing str", but when I'm inputting the same in the html form, it just get stuck while I pressed the submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a "forms" portion to your setup will help you greatly... see the quickstart docs on forms here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/

In particular, check out "using a form in a view": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Basically, you end up with a "forms.py" file which defines your form fields. Then, after it all processes, you get a simplier API into your form fields that looks like this:

```
form.cleaned_data['recipient']
form.cleaned_data['content']
```

etc.

Comment: thanks I will probably use that to handle my forms from now on.